# Specifying data format in Rails for SimpleForm and Boostrap DateTime picker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I'm using the Boostrap DateTime picker gem (https://github.com/lubieniebieski/bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails) with simple form and the problem is as follows:

In order to get the input field to look as it should (see http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ for example) I need to do the following:

```
    #apptime.input-append
        = f.input :app_time, :label => "Time", :wrapper => :append do
          = f.input_field :app_time, :as => :string, input_html: { "data-format" => "hh:mm:ss" }
          %span.add-on
            %i{"data-date-icon" => "icon-calendar", "data-time-icon" => "icon-time"}
```

Which renders the following HTML

```
    <input type="text" size="50" name="deal[app_time]" input_html="{"data-format"=>"hh:mm:ss"}" id="deal_app_time" class="string optional">
```

Note how it renders incorrectly renders

```
    input_html: { "data-format" => "hh:mm:ss" }
```

Where as

```
      #datetime.input-append
        = f.input :app_time, :as => :string, input_html: { "data-format" => "hh:mm:ss" }
        %span.add-on
          %i{"data-date-icon" => "icon-calendar", "data-time-icon" => "icon-time"}
```

renders the correct HTML, but messes up the bootstrap form field. So my question is how should I specify data-format using simple forms 'input_field'

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm struggling with getting datetimepicker working on my app.
Did you see this?: https://github.com/lubieniebieski/bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails/pull/5
If you can get it working with that, could you tell me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay got it working like this:

```
.datetime.input-append
  = f.input :mikor, :label => "Time", :wrapper => :append do
    = f.input_field :mikor, :as => :string, "data-format" => "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss" 
    %span.add-on
      %i{"data-date-icon" => "icon-calendar", "data-time-icon" => "icon-time"}
```

Looks like we don't need to put data-format inside input_html this way.